# How to interpret the output shape from an Embedding layer in Keras, when used with one-hot encoded vectors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, embedding

I have a large set of consumer products, each which are assigned to multiple categories.  For example, a jacket can be in both the "Sports" and "Outdoors" categories.

There are many, many categories (~1000), and I want to create a lower-dimensional embedding that I can use to compare products for similarity.

I started by creating a set of one-hot encoded representing each product:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/one-hot.csv")
df.head()

#             Sports  Mens   Womens   Outdoor
# Product 1     1       1       0        1      ...
# Product 2     0       0       1        1      ...
# ...~30000 more products
```

...and then created a Keras embedding layer.  Since there are 1000 possible categories, the total vocabulary size is 1000 (correct?).  I'm projecting into 10 dimensions, and each product vector has a length of 1000.

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1000, 10, input_length=1000))
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
model.summary()

# Model: "sequential_17"
# _________________________________________________________________
# Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
# =================================================================
# embedding_17 (Embedding)     (None, 1000, 10)          10000     
# =================================================================
# Total params: 10,000
# Trainable params: 10,000
# Non-trainable params: 0

output = model.predict(df)
print(output.shape)
print(output.ndim)

# (30000, 1000, 10)
# 3
```

I'm struggling to understand the output shape.  I had expected a 2d vector (30,000, 10), where each row is a single product, and the values are the embedding values.

Am incorrectly setting up the embedding layer, or am I misunderstanding what the output vector represents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your `Embedding` instance:

- Embedding takes integers, not one-hot encoded values.
- You set `input_length=1000`, which is meant for a sequence of integer values, not the dimensionality of the input. This affects the number of timesteps in the input and output, so you should leave this parameter out:

  ```
  model.add(Embedding(1000, 10))
  ```